# Data type error, alphanumeric not working

Tags: excel, types

I am running a database in Access from within Excel VBA, using data from excel. When I use number as entry, say 12, on the field ClientID, it appends to the database from excel, even though the cell in which the field value is formatted as text and the data type of the CliendID field is set to TEXT(255).
When I change the value to "123ABC" it shows the message "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '123ABC'."

When I change the value to "ABC123" it shows the error message: "No value given for one or more required parameters."

I don't have much experience in SQL and have no clue why is this happening, one solution would be to change the clientID to numbers, but a lot of existing regiters I have are already alphanumeric.
The code is writen in excel vba.
Any help muchly appreciated.
Edit:

```
Sub CreateTables()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim strpath As String, constr As String
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Dim conn As Object

    strpath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("strpathClients")

    ' CONNECT TO DATABASE '
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strpath & ";"
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open constr

    conn.Execute "CREATE TABLE Clients (" _
                    & " ClientID TEXT(255)," _
                    & " ClientName TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Address TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Notes TEXT(255)," _
                    & " DateCreated DATETIME" _
                    & ");"
    conn.Execute "CREATE TABLE Orders (" _
                    & " OrderID AUTOINCREMENT," _
                    & " ClientID TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Item TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Price DOUBLE," _
                    & " OrderDate DATETIME," _
                    & " Notes TEXT(255)" _
                    & ");"
    ' CLOSE CONNECTION '
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully created Clients and Orders tables!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

    ErrHandle:
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub ActionQueriesAPPEND()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim strpath As String, constr As String
    Dim conn As Object

    strpath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("strpathClients")

    ' OPEN CONNECTION '
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strpath & ";"
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open constr
    'MsgBox Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
    ' APPEND QUERY '
    conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Clients (ClientID, ClientName)" _
                    & " VALUES (" & Worksheets(1).Range("A2") & ", '" & 
                    Worksheets(1).Range("B2") & "');"

    conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Orders (ClientID, Item, Price)" _
                    & " VALUES (" & Worksheets(1).Range("A2") & ", " _
                    & "'" & Worksheets(1).Range("C2") & "', " _
                    & Worksheets(1).Range("D2") & ");"


    ' CLOSE CONNECTION '
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully updated database!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

    ErrHandle:
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Range("d24") = Err.Description
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to post your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've tried but it formats the text funny. Can I just copy and paste in a comment in here?

Comment: I added the code, for some reason it separated sections of the same routine in shaded and non shaded areas, I hope it works like this (this is my first post in here ever!!)

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: at the line conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Clients (ClientID, ClientName)" _
                    & " VALUES (" & Worksheets(1).Range("A2") & ", '" & 
                    Worksheets(1).Range("B2") & "');"

Comment: @TimWilliams: I noted you edited my write up! I guess one has to follow certain rules to post code in here, eh? thanks!

Comment: @Tony - it's pretty difficult to read code if you double/triple space the lines: a lot of scrolling up and down, without much code visible in any given screen.  Not a big deal though.

Comment: I would comment out the error handler so you can see more easily exactly where the error(s) are.  Also put your SQL into a string and debug.print it before passing it to `Execute` so you can be sure it's exactly as you expect. The one thing I see is you're not putting single quotes around the value for ClientId in your SQL: you need those since you've defined the field as Text..

Comment: this is what I did and I get the same error: << "INSERT INTO Clients (" & " 'ClientID' " & ", ClientName)" _>>  I also tried this <<"INSERT INTO Clients ('ClientID' , ClientName)" _ >> with the same error

Comment: Correction, I was trying on the wrong part, I did id like your sample and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Clients (ClientID, ClientName)" _
                & " VALUES (" & Worksheets(1).Range("A2") & ", '" & 
                Worksheets(1).Range("B2") & "');"
```

missing single quotes around the value for ClientId

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Clients (ClientID, ClientName)" _
                & " VALUES ('" & Worksheets(1).Range("A2") & "', '" & 
                Worksheets(1).Range("B2") & "')"
```